# change header color on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, offset, scrolltop

I'm trying to make the element `#site-header` change background color when the div `#primary` approaches the top of the page. I'm doing this by appending a class of `.white-head` to `#primary` using the following code

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > $("#primary").offset().top) {
        $('#site-header').addClass('white-head');
    } else {
        $('#site-header').removeClass('white-head');
    }
});
```

I have been over the code 1000000 times and cannot for the life of me work out why this is nor working nay ideas?

Here is the CSS:

```
.white-head {
    background: white!important;
}
#site-header {
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: can you add your styles for `#page-header` and `.white-head`.  I'm guessing it's a specificity error

Comment: added to the the original question

Comment: Your styles are for `#site-header`?  but try this: `#page-header.white-head { background: white; }` (also I think there is meant to be a space between white and !)

Comment: you are right... they should be for `#site-header` but its still not working even know its been updated.

Comment: NEVER MIND... the issue was in the way I included jQuery! thanks anyway